# change color of A tag of bootsrap not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <head>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    **<style>
      .navbar-brand{
        color:red;
      }**
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        **<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Test</a>**
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>    
</body>
```

I want to change the color of the Text to Red, but It's not working.
It will work if I put "Test" in a span and set style to the span.

Comment: If I set style to ".navbar-brand and .navbar-header" class It's gone work. But why set to just .navbar-brand class not working ?!

Comment: Please show us a live example.

Comment: @manoj Kumar, http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=qjatnPR9Ep

Comment: Strange that Internal CSS is not having higher priority than External.

Comment: have you tried placing the CSS directly in to your anchor tag?

Comment: Yes, when I put inside A tag It's working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
  .navbar-brand{
    color:red !important;
  }
</style>
```

just add !important to the end of your css color attribute.

EDITED

when !important is used, its associated property and value will overwrite all other contradicting CSS, wherever it may be.

Comment: and, what is "!important" ?

Comment: when !important is used, its associated property and value will overwrite all other contradicting CSS, wherever it may be.

Comment: It's a tmp fix. why  Internal CSS is not having higher priority than External ?

Comment: Maybe bootstrap team used !important in their External library.

Comment: It's not the answer, but It's the best one.

Comment: (A tip) When you use (color:red !important;) in bootstrap you force the html to ignore bootstrap for the class .btn-danger which is already there made by bootstrap team and that could cause a heavy load unless if your work roles forcing you to don't add any codes to HTML pages (Which in not recommend it).

Comment: You don't have to use (color:red !important;) in your html you can use it in a seprate css file and link to that css file just in this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this since you use bootstrap you apply `.btn-danger` to `<div class=" btn-danger navbar-header">`